# angular-translate - multiple languages on the same page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internationalization

I'm building a questionnaire type app where you have the first person language on top and you have the exact same question on the bottom in a different language.

right now i'm data binding all question to one big object like this.
lanOneQuestion
lanTwoQuestion
and each question has like lanOneQuestion.one that corresponds to the each question.  I get the string of data from a big json document.

I'm wondering if I could use angular-translate, but I didn't see a way to use multiple language's at the same time?

Comment: for SEO, you shouldn't use multiple languages on same page.

Comment: Ya.  But i need to allow the person to distributing the questionnaire to be able to read it and the person taking the questionnaire to be able to also read to read it.  So you have to take one for the team some days.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code

```
translatedWord = $translate.instant(YOUR_KEY,{},"",YOUR_LANGUAGE);
```

You can check this

https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate/pull/1328

Comment: This only works for angular 1, how about angular version > 2